# How to check if data inserted succesfully to data base through android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, pdo

I have an android code that inserts using php data to MySQL table, in case the data wasn't inserted successfully I want to inform the user that the data wasn't inserted, how can I send the android app a message that will tell if the data was inserted or not?

my php code for insert is:

```
    <?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=android',$uname,$pwd);

// Check connection

    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];


$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample(id, name)
    VALUES(:id, :name)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "id" => $id,
    "name" => $name


));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it will works...

```
    <?php
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=android',$uname,$pwd);

// Check connection

    $id=$_POST["id"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];


$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample(id, name)
    VALUES(:id, :name)");
$statement ->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement ->bindParam(':nmae', $name);
$statement->execute();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $conn->lastInsertId() to check the last record that was inserted into the database.